# Survey123 cannot communicate with map viewer

Tags: arcgis-survey123

I created a survey and published it to my organization. However, in the survey123 webpage, when I try to use the "open in Map Viewer" tool to view the attribute table, I get an error that says "accessing data failed" Does anyone know why I can't view the attribute table this way?

Also, in the new map viewer, it does not give me the option to view the attribute table.

[image]

Comment: Did you try accessing the data through the "Data Tab" on the item description page? Add a few screenshots?

Comment: I'll add screenshots, but yes I can access the data through the Data Tab

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found this in the esri technical articles. I think they are trying to protect us from ourselves...

https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000028133